# Are there any influences of other religion on Hinduism?

Tags: culture, tradition, other-religions

In ancient time, Hindu tradition and culture had been ruled many regions in the world. But, when time passed other religion had come. So, they were taken and debt some traditions. So, Which influences were found in Hinduism of other religion?

Comment: Dowry, pardah (covering face), sunday holiday are some of the practice which are relics left by conquerors.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all our sacred texts refer to our religion as sanathana dharma instead of hinduism. These words are only given recently by conquerors and if we take sanathana dharma into account there is no influence of any other religion as name itself suggests that this is the first set of rules for life on earth

Comment: Good Answer. I will go somewhat further beyond in saying that the set of rules mentioned in Vedas (Which Sanatana Dharma is following) are the eternal rules of this universe.Also pls. do try to add some sources in the answer.